# IPython to use Python27 in Amazon EC2

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, ipython

I have some code that runs on Python27 and Amazon EC2 nodes have Python26 as the default.  I have installed Python27 alongside Python26 and can call it directly using python27.  However if I install IPython

```
pip install ipython
```

It install iPython for python26 and always calls that one.  Is there a way to ensure the IPython I install is for Python27?  Or do I need to do something so that pip installs libraries for Python27?

EDIT:
I changed my default python to point to Python27 and it solved my original issues.  However yum is no longer working (this may or may not be a problem as I don't know if I'll ever need it again).  Is there a way for these things to coexist!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to install packages for a particular Python is to do either:

```
pip-2.7 install ipython
```

which may not exist, or

```
python27 -m pip install ipython
```

which ensures that Python 2.7 is used, and thus the packages are installed in the right locations to be picked up by 2.7.

However, it may be cleanest to just create a virtualenv with Python 2.7:

```
virtualenv -p python27 ~/env/py27
```

And when you use that, it's easier to be sure which Python you are using, without messing with the system-wide install of things.
Many people find virtualenvs the easiest / cleanest way to use the non-default Python on a given system.

Comment: Quick followup to that...How do I install other libraries for the virtualenv?

Comment: once you activate the virtualenv, just do `pip install [package]`, and it will install in the env instead of system-wide.